# How do I make sure everything in my scene is in proportion to my character?

Tags: modeling, scale

I'm looking at modeling a little scene and I'm looking for some advice. I want a short animation where my character moves from one room to another then heads outside and walks down a street. What my issue is I'm not sure about sizes. I want everything to be in proportion so that nothing looks ridiculously to large or small etc. and when outside I dont want my character to look out of place. I hope someone gets the jist of what im trying to explain and may be able to advise me.

Comment: Hi. What is it about sizes you're not sure about?

Comment: just making sure that everything looks right in the scene and not like out of place like my character is modeled at 6ft3 so trying to get all the other objects to be like if it was real world scene sizes so that nothing is overlly to large or 2 small and when outside with the building i dont want things such as the building doors or windows look out of place and size  against my character

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common problem in (architectural) modeling.
I'll answer it as objectively as I can.

To get a good sense of real world scale:

**Universal tips**

1. Learn the size of everyday objects.
   Get up and manually measure your windows, doors, ceiling height, etc.
   You'll find that nothing is arbitrary, everything has a purpose.
2. Model by blueprints
   Nothing beats physical experience, but blueprints and floor plans help to save time considerably, when modeling extra large/tiny objects.
3. Get a reference source.
   Architects are one step ahead of you there.  *[Neufert's Architects' Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architects%27_Data)* is a reference book for spatial requirements in architecture. From optimal height of door handles, to minimal size of toilet bowls `/s`.

**Blender tips**

1. Model in real world scale.
   Set Blender to a unit system that you use in everyday life.
   *Properties panel > Scene > Units*

[image]

2. Use orthographic view - this will allow for a more precise modeling
   Shortcut: <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>

[image]